# Batch File rename give the "The filename ... syntax is incorrect" error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I got a folder with that contain a couple of files without any extention and I want to change them all to be with the txt extention.

```
@echo off
SET filename=%0

SET d=%filename:renaming.bat"="%
SET d=%d:"=%

ren "%d%*\*" *.txt
```

I assumed that all the files in the all the folders in the same folder as my batch file (renaming.bat) will have the txt extention.

but I got "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." error . can Anyone help me on the matter plz ??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple to do from the cmd line. You can do this in a batch file.  I am just doing it from the cmd line to show you the results.

```
C:\temp>dir /b *.
file1
file2
file3

C:\temp>rename *. *.txt

C:\temp>dir /b
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

C:\temp>
```

Code to parse all sub folders for files with no extension.

```
for /R %%G IN (*.) do ren "%%~G" "%%~nG.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks ,I know I can do it per folder separately each time but what I tried is like this:
think that you got "M" folders that each folder got "N" files, I would rather not to enter each direcotry and launch that script , What Im trying to do is to pack all those folders under one folder that contain that bach file and then just launch it.

Comment: great work like a charm , could you any source that you recomend on where  I can learn more about that kind of area ? ( batch file )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this. It might be helpful
https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rename.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: thanks but I already visit this page and I still can't see what the problem with my code . I did'nt try to change files in a couple of diffrent drives or something like they mention there.